# Quiero encontrar el atributo cedula para buscar y saber si existe

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

package com.cmc.evaluacion.fase2.entidades;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Cartera {
ArrayList cliente;

```
public ArrayList<Cliente> getCliente() {
    return cliente;
}

public ArrayList<Cliente> buscarCliente(String cedula){
    if()
    return null;
}
```

}

cree una atributo del tipo ArrayList; dentro de Cliente tengo un atributo cedula, quiero encontrar el atributo cedula para hacer un if y saber si existe.Me dicen que debo usar un enhaced for, pero no se cómo

Answer (score 2):

Tu clase ``Cliente debe ser algo como

```
public class Cliente{
   private String cedula;
   //Los demás atributos

  public String getCedula() {
        return cedula;
    }
}
```

Si lo que quieres saber si existe cliente, entonces tu método `buscarCliente` debe retornar un booleano.
La clase `Cartera` quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
public class Cartera {
    private ArrayList<Cliente> clientes;

    public Cartera() {
        clientes= new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public boolean buscarCliente(String cedula){
            boolean existe=false;
            for(Cliente c:clientes){
                if(c.getCedula().equals(cedula)){
                    existe=true;
                }            
            }
            return existe;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Puedes acortar retornando directamente dentro del `if` si existe y al terminar el bucle si no se encontró el cliente retornar false

Comment: @JFrame tienes razón amigo, en las clases de programación enseñan así cuando están aprendiendo